# What architecture to choose (WCF services, server side logic)

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture

I am developing server side logic to process requests and respond with data to front-end server as well as to mobile app direct connections.

I have implemented SessionContext class that basically ensures, that there is matching session record in DB for every service that is called (with exception for forgot password cases, etc).

I am now trying to implement event logging. I want to have common logic so I may log all requests, exceptions, data, etc.

I have come up with this code, but somehow I don't feel good about it - too much code for each service method. Are there any clever tricks that I might implement to make it shorter and easier to read/code?

Current implementation would use EventLogic class to log event to event table. At some point some events might be related to session so I am passing eventLog as parameter to SessionContext (to create link between event and session). SessionContext saves entity data on successful dispose... i have a gut feeling that something is wrong with my design.

```
public Session CreateUser(string email, string password, System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress)
{
    using (var eventLog = new EventLogic())
    {
        try
        {
            eventLog.LogCreateUser(email, password, ipAddress);

            using (var context = SessionContext.CreateUser(eventLog, email, password, ipAddress))
            {
                return new Session()
                {
                    Id = context.Session.UId,
                    HasExpired = context.Session.IsClosed,
                    IsEmailVerified = context.Session.User.IsEmailVerified,
                    TimeCreated = context.Session.TimeCreated,
                    PublicUserId = CryptoHelper.GuidFromId(context.Session, context.Session.UserId, CryptoHelper.TargetTypeEnum.PublicUser),
                    ServerTime = context.Time
                };
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            eventLog.Exception(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a more generic approach like eventLog.Log(exception) and eventLog.Log(classname, methodname, serializedMessage, isOutgoing); or you can use an available lib like log4net.

Comment: What do you need this log data for?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using something like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) (for example) for logging.

If your classes follow [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), you should have not more than one call type like `LogCreateUser` per your application. And that means, there is no need to extract logging logic into a new class.